# How to customize authentication fields in fire-base and react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am building an app with react native and I want to use fire-base to authenticate users, but I don't want to use third party sign in method therefore I want to customize my authentication fields and I don't know how to.

**any suggestions? 
any tutorial suggestions?**

Comment: This is a very broad question.